# Computed column out of two aggregated columns in Elasticsearch/Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Let's say I have a simple aggregation as follows:

```
| Item | Views | Clicks |
+------+-------+--------+
| B    | 123   | 34     |
| A    | 234   | 12     |
| C    | 56    | 2      |
```

Is it possible to generate an additional column as a computed result of the Views and Clicks columns? For example:

```
| Item | Views | Clicks | Ratio |
+------+-------+--------+-------+
| B    | 123   | 34     | 0.28  |
| A    | 234   | 12     | 0.05  |
| C    | 56    | 2      | 0.03  |
```

It would also be ideal to be able to sort on this additional column.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of aggregation through Elasticsearch (and Kibana)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pipeline aggregations with scripting support for this. A disadvantage is that you have to enable inline scripting or put the script in a file. To enable support for inline scripting add this to your yaml.

```
script.inline: on
```

Below an example:

```
POST /items/item/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "1" }}
{"name": "A","views": 2,"clicks": 3}
{ "index": { "_id": "2" }}
{"name": "A","views": 1,"clicks": 9}
{ "index": { "_id": "3" }}
{"name": "B","views": 5,"clicks": 15}
{ "index": { "_id": "4" }}
{"name": "C","views": 1,"clicks": 1}
{ "index": { "_id": "5" }}
{"name": "A","views": 3,"clicks": 23}

GET /items/item/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "byName": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "countClicks": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "clicks"
          }
        },
        "countViews": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "views"
          }
        },
        "computeRatio": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "the_clicks": "countClicks",
              "the_views": "countViews"
            },
            "script": "the_clicks / the_views"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the bucket script aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a scripted field in Kibana, which will provide you with desired results.

To create a scripted field in Kibana, following the below steps:

- In Kibana, click on Settings tab and then click on your index pattern
- You should see 2 tabs "Fields" and "Scripted fields".
- Click on the "Scripted fields" tab. Then "Add scripted field".
- Enter the "Name" in the Script field as Ratio and  enter the following:-

  doc['clicks'].value / doc['views'].value
- Click "Create Field" at the bottom. Now your scripted field will be added & can be viewed from Discover page.